# message box for duplicate items

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi everyone iv been trying for about an hour to find a simple code which makes my "Add Contact" form check if there are no duplicates of the field "ext" but i cant seem to get it to work :(

Basically it needs to check if there is already a ext number of the same value and then give a message saying "Extension Number already exists"

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("phonebook") or die(mysql_error());
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
$checkSql="select count(id) as eCount from address";
$result = mysql_query($checkSql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['eCount'] == 999) {
    $disable = 1;
}
switch($mode) {
    case 'add':
  ?>
<h2>Add Contact</h2>
<form name="form1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=added" method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <table class="searchable">
            <tr><td>Extension:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" name="ext" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Name:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Department:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" name="department" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" name="email" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cellphone:</td><td><div align="left">
                <input type="text" name="phone" />
            </div></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a> | <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Add New Contact" <?php if($disable ==1){?>disabled<?php } ?>/></td></tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="added">
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
break;
case 'added':
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $ext = $_POST ['ext'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO address (ext, name, department ,email, phone) VALUES ('" . $ext . "','" . $name . "','" . $department . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $phone . "')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
break;
```

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
$checkSql="select count(id) as eCount from address where ext = " . $_POST['ext'];
```

However, you are using the deprecated version of MySQL. Consider updating to MySQLi or PDO instead.

You can also update your code to give an error message. For example:

```
if($row['eCount'] > 0) {
    echo "Extension Number already exists";
    $mode = 'add';
}
```

This would check to see whether or not the extension number already exists, print the error message, and display the form again.

Comment: could you help me with one more thing if possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this below code to below  $ext = $_POST ['ext'];  and i hope you close the bracket '}' of switch case if yes then remove last bracket from my solution code i hope it's helpfull for you


$check_ext ="SELECT * FROM address WHERE ext = ".$ext;
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    $checked_ext = mysqli_query($con,$check_ext);
    $data_chk = mysqli_fetch_array($checked_ext, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($data_chk[0]>1)
    {echo "Extension Number already exists";}
    else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO address (ext, name, department ,email, phone) VALUES ('" . $ext . "','" . $name . "','" . $department . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $phone . "')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
    break;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you used switch. I didn't use it but as you mentioned i check before adding extention no and if already exist then wii give a message otherwise added as new record.

```
index.php



     <?php
        $message = '';
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("phonebook") or die(mysql_error());
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $ext = $_POST['ext'];   
        $checkSql = "select count(id) as eCount from address where ext = " . $_POST['ext']."";
        $result = mysql_query($checkSql);
        $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($data['eCount'] == 0){   
// as you have check it to 999 so if you want that it should be less than or equal to 999 times only then you can check `$data['eCount']<= 999` then do entry otherwise error message
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $ext = $_POST ['ext'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO address (ext, name, department ,email, phone) VALUES ('" . $ext . "','" . $name . "','" . $department . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $phone . "')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        $message = "Entery has been done successfully";
        $_POST = array();
        }else {

            $message = "Selected extension  number $ext already exist";
        }
        }
        ?>

        <h2>Add Contact</h2>
        <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
            <div align="center">
                <table class="searchable">
                 <tr><td colspan="2"><h3><?php echo $message;?></h3></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Extension:</td><td><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="ext" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ext'])){echo $_POST['ext'];}?>" />
                    </div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Name:</td><td><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){echo $_POST['name'];}?>" />
                    </div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Department:</td><td><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="department" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['department'])){echo $_POST['department'];}?>"/>
                    </div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Email:</td><td><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo $_POST['email'];}?>"/>
                    </div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Cellphone:</td><td><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['phone'])){echo $_POST['phone'];}?>" />
                    </div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a> | <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Add New Contact"/></td></tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```